# Wrap long sentences in a table (Table looks awkward): Any help please

Tags: tabularx

```
\documentclass{arttcle}

\begin{document}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{table}[H]

\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}

\caption{Reviews}

\label{table1}

\scriptsize

\centering

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}

\renewcommand\tabcolsep{3.0pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X X X c}

\hline

\textbf{Number} & \textbf{Stage} & \textbf{Problem} & \textbf{State} & 
\textbf{Objective} & \textbf{Referee}  \\

\hline                              

SEIR & Real-time Analysis & Differential & Stochastic 

& Estimation of the basic and effective reproductive numbers of the $2014$ infectious disease in Africa & 

\citep{althaus2014} \\

\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
```

Comment: The posted code produces `! LaTeX Error: File \`arttcle.cls' not found.` If I fix that it produces `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.` as `\usepackage` is too late If I move `\begin{document}` after the packages I get `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`H'.` Please fix the example to show the problem that you ask in the title.

Answer (score 6):

Please test your examples before posting.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,float,caption,natbib}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}
\caption{Reviews}
\label{table1}
\scriptsize
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}
\renewcommand\tabcolsep{3.0pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llll>{\raggedright}Xl}
\hline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{Stage} & \textbf{Problem} & \textbf{State} & 
\textbf{Objective} & \textbf{Referee}  \\
\hline                              
SEIR & Real-time Analysis & Differential & Stochastic 
& Estimation of the basic and effective reproductive
  numbers of the $2014$ infectious disease in Africa & 
\citep{althaus2014} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mr. David Carlisle, this looks very good. Sure, I will do better next time. Thanks for your time.